# PayPal orders set to status “Suspected Fraud” in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.9

This question is asked before here but I didn't get my answer. so I am asking it again if there is any genius who across this problem and solved it then help me to solve.

I am using Paypal payment method in my magneto store and it's working perfect for placing order with status pending after few hours it's status change to processing and when we shipped order it's status become complete. However after few hours of complete status it's become "Suspected Fraud" and because of this issue I can not create invoice.

So please help me to solve this problem and why this problem is occur I don't know.So please anyone is here who can let me know the reason behind this problem and solution.

I hope someone had face this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, this probably comes down to conversion rates.

Take a look at http://www.hummingbirduk.com/suspected-fraud-transactions-magento/ I think it's a great walkthrough of this, and offers some good steps for reducing impact and possibly identifying the issue in your store.

Comment: Radbum Thanks for your answer And I follow that link and I got solution.

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887028/create-paypal-sandbox-merchant-seller-account)