# Create Paypal Sandbox merchant/seller account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

i saw [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694105/how-to-set-up-a-paypal-sandbox-seller-account-a-buyer-account-and-an-applic) for creating paypal seller account . but when i visited https://developer.paypal.com

Dashboard > Sandbox> Accounts > I can not see "Create account" button.

seems the site changed the configuration options for creating sandbox account.

please guide me how to set up merchant sandbox account

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry to ask you the question but are you logged ?
I just verifyed and i can see the button...

Comment: No, i did't logged in. i didt saw the "create account " button, did you followed this way : `Dashboard > Sandbox> Accounts > I can not see "Create account" button.`

Comment: No. First create account and then log in.
Go to Dashboard > sandbox > accounts and you'll be able to see the "create button".

Comment: are you telling me to "sign up" first in this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/) ?

Comment: Yes, sign up if you have no account else log in.

Comment: can we test "payment" through sandbox credntials. means can we pay the money online through sandbox credentails

Comment: Not with real money ?
Of course, its the purpose with sandbox. I think you should take a look to this tutorial : [link](http://www.webassist.com/tutorials/PayPal-Sandbox-for-testing)